# Which query does the search api execute by default in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch, i can access the default search api like
`server: 9200/index/_search?q=keyword` but how can i replicate this if I am building the query myself? I've tried multi_match and query string, but the result set seem a bit different than the default search api.

PS: i am using elasticsearch PHP client, if that matters

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent query to `server:9200/index/_search?q=keyword` is a [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#_parameters_3) like this one

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```